# how to change contentView frame in cellforrowatindexpath?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have made a custom cell and i want to change the frame of contentView. My cell is a CustomCell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"hey");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellReuseID";

    AbcCustomCell *cell = [tabel_Abc dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AbcCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *name= [arrayTabel_Abc objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


    [cell.label_CellList setText:name];

   cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake (100,0,500,20);


    return cell;
    }
```

I have use
        cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake (100,0,500,20);
but its not working for me. I want to change the contentView of customCell, Can any one guide me?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using autolayout or not ?

Comment: Yes I am using AutoLayout in UITableVIewCustomCell

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the contentView. UITableViewCell contentView's height is determined by `– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method and its width is the tableView's width normally.

If you can add a view as subview of contentView and change the view's frame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-assign the frame for the cell's contentView.

```
CGRect oldFrame = cell.contentView.frame;
cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake( oldFrame.origin.x,
                                 oldFrame.origin.y, 
                                 oldFrame.size.width + 20, 
                                 oldFrame.size.height );
```

or you may use custom cell

Comment: just try custom cell to change contentview in layoutsubview

Answer (score 0):

you can't change the frame of contentView of a cell. you can change the height of a cell by using

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

But you can't change the width.

Also you can use a view if you want to make as if the divider is big, if you want something like that.

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width - paddingX*2, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

Can you be more specific to which frame you want to change(whether it is out of bounds)?